# facebook notifications alert from facebook API/using facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going to create a new mobile app which will be mainly used to track the notifications of 2 or 3 facebook accounts together in one app. I just want to know the following: is it possible to get immediate alert of notification from facebook API/using facebook API for each account by having the facebook login credentials and valid access token alone?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe for [Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3).

> The Graph API has a feature called 'Real Time Updates' that enables
>   apps to subscribe to changes in certain pieces of data. When a change
>   occurs, an HTTP 'POST' request will be sent to a callback URL
>   belonging to that app. This makes apps more efficient, as they know
>   exactly when a change has happened, and don't need to rely on
>   continuous or even periodic Graph API requests when changes aren't
>   happening.
>
> Note that real-time updates only indicate that a particular field has
>   changed, they do not include the value of those fields. They should be
>   used only to indicate when a new Graph API request to that field needs
>   to be made.

You can subscribe for changes in a single object or in an array of objects. See [Receiving the Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3#receiveupdates) section.